# How would I get the current time (Not 24 hours) using datetime in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to use the timestamp function to just display the time someone edited their message.
Currently, this is my code:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
 if before.author != self.bot.user:
  embed=discord.Embed(title="{}".format(before.author), description="Editted a Message:",color=0xfcca03)
  embed.add_field(name= "**Before:** " ,value=before.content, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name= "**After:** ",value=after.content, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="**Details:** ", value = "Channel: " + str(after.channel) + "\n" + "ID: " + str({before.author.id}))
  guild = self.bot.get_guild(357331299792584707)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url = guild.icon_url)
  timestamp = datetime.now() 
  embed.set_footer(text=guild.name + "Timestamp: " + str(timestamp))
  channel = self.bot.get_channel(722949984227688519)
  await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

The code works but the timestamp is full of other information I don't need.

Example: `Timestamp: 2020-11-13 17:48:24.876424`

How would I make it so it looks something like this? "Timestamp: 7:43 PM"

Any help would greatly help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of simply converting the datetime to str, look into `strftime()` to [format the string you want.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) In your case you would want to use the `%I:%M %p`

Answer (score 5):

You may use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)

```
timestamp = datetime.now()
print(timestamp)                        # 2020-11-13 19:12:26.718388
print(timestamp.strftime(r"%I:%M %p"))  # 07:12 PM
```

Specifically with the following [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

- `%I` for *Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number*
- `%p` for *Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM*
- `%M` for *Minute as a zero-padded decimal number*